# Install yum packages without internet connection

Tags: centos7, yum

Is there any way to download all packages from this line, save them locally and then install them to a machine without an internet connection?

```
yum install -y qemu-kvm qemu-img virt-manager libvirt libvirt-python libvirt-client virt-install virt-viewer bridge-utils
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `--downloadonly` command.

Run `yum install qemu-kvm qemu-img virt-manager libvirt libvirt-python libvirt-client virt-install virt-viewer bridge-utils --downloadonly` it will prompt to install but it wont and will instead show;

```
yum install procmail --downloadonly
Installed size: 385 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y         
Downloading Packages:
exiting because --downloadonly specified
```

By default the downloaded files are in; `/var/cache/yum/`

There are some more details [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10154) on the RedHat page.

Comment: In case you want to download to a different directory: `yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=<directory> <package>`